# Redux-toolkit: should I use both useSelector and useCallback

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-redux

I was previously using `useSelector` from Redux using something like:

```
  const todo = useSelector((state) => state.todos[props.id])
```

as documented. However, in another related library called [proxy-memorize](https://github.com/dai-shi/proxy-memoize), they recommend instead to use (for their own library):

```
useSelector(useCallback(memoize(state => ({ … }))))
```

but now I’m confused: should I use `useCallback` inside `useSelector` generally when I’m not using proxy-memorize? If not, why does proxy-memorize requires it?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> useSelector(useCallback(memoize(state => ({ … }))))
> ```
>
> but now I’m confused: should I use `useCallback` inside `useSelector`
> generally when I’m not using `proxy-memorize`?

Generally, no, you do not need to memoize the selector function via the `useCallback` hook, `useSelector((state) => state.todos[props.id])` is fine. React-redux and the `useSelector` hook applies some [equality checks during updates](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates). Italicized and bolded text emphasis is mine to highlight what I believe to be relevant with regards to selector function reference stability.

> When the function component renders, the provided selector function
> will be called and its result will be returned from the `useSelector()`
> hook. (*A cached result **may** be returned by the hook without re-running
> the selector if it's the **same function reference** as on a previous
> render of the component.*)
>
> However, when an action is dispatched to the Redux store,
> `useSelector()` only forces a re-render if the selector result appears
> to be different than the last result. The default comparison is a
> strict `===` reference comparison.

> If not, why does proxy-memorize requires it?

Note also from the docs that

> With `useSelector()`, returning a new object every time will always
> force a re-render by default.

Where one of the proposed solutions is

> Use Reselect or a similar library to create a memoized selector that
> returns multiple values in one object, but only returns a new object
> when one of the values has changed.

Using `useSelector(state => ({ … }))` would trigger a force rerender even if the returned object was equivalent. The `memoize` function from `proxy-memoize` serves to ***memoize the returned result***, and wrapping it in the `useCallback` hook serves to memoize, e.g. provide, ***a stable function reference*** to the `useSelector` hook. `useSelector(useCallback(memoize(state => ({ … }))))` provides the broadest form of stability optimization by memoizing (A) the selector callback function, and (B) memoizing the selector function results. Note in the [usage with react redux](https://github.com/dai-shi/proxy-memoize#usage-with-react-redux--reselect) section this is the suggested pattern to use if you are not using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

I've not ever heard of proxy-memoize, but a Reselect version of the code may look something like the following:

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'; // *

const selectTodos = state => state.todos;

export const selectTodoById = createSelector(
  [todos, (state, id) => id],
  (todos, id) => todos[id],
);
```

```js
const todo = useSelector((state) => selectTodoById(props.id))
```

The `selectTodoById` selector function is a memoized selector, e.g. memoizes the selected `todo` object using the `state.todos` and passed `id` value as inputs. Only when either of these two values changes the selector function recompute its value, otherwise it simply returns the memoized value.

**** Note:** If you are using Redux-Toolkit, it re-exports all of `Reselect` (the same maintainers of `Redux`, `React-Redux`, and `Redux-Toolkit` also maintain `Reselect`):*

```js
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I understand why memoize is needed in `proxy-memoize` (that is actually recommended by redux: `we officially encourage considering using proxy-memoize` in https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors), I’m just unsure to understand why in `useSelector((state) => state.todos[props.id])` the function `(state) => state.todos[props.id]` is not giving a new function reference at every render (for instance if I do `{x: 42}` two times, I would end up with two references, and if I run `((state) => state.todos[props.id]) == ((state) => state.todos[props.id])` this returns false.

Comment: @tobiasBora React-Redux has been optimized a lot too. We'd probably need to dig into the source to see exactly what the `useSelector` hook does with the callback function passed to it.

Comment: Uhm… I wanted to avoid looking at the source as I’m not a redux expert, but I might give it a try (or do actual experiments) as I’m still very confused why `useCallback` is needed in one case and not in the other… To me it either always consider different functions a the same, or never, but I don’t see how it could consider them sometimes as equal when the reference is different. Unless it is smart enough to see if a function has a side effect (which memoize has to keep the cache updated) before comparing their code… but that sounds like not trivial to do.

Comment: @tobiasBora Oh, I see. I don't think it's needed at all. It's likely recommended by the `proxy-memoize` maintainers to be used since it provides a stable function reference which generally aides React settle any dependency checks.

Comment: So you mean I should also use `useCallback` in `useSelector((state) => state.todos[props.id])`, even if people don’t care too much in practice because `state.todos[props.id]` is anyway really quick to evaluate, and `useSelector` will anyway perform a check at the end with the value obtained last time to see if a re-render must be done?

Comment: @tobiasBora I think I'm saying the opposite. This post is literally the first time I've ever seen it suggested to use the `useCallback` hook to provide a stable reference selector function to the `useSelector` hook. Typically we'd either declare the function outside React, so it's a stable reference, or memoize it, most commonly with Reselect. That said, it *does* appear that `proxy-memoize` has a unique and interesting approach to Redux state selection.